# why does pipenv install only work for some modules?

Tags: python

I use pipenv for my Python development cause it makes things easier. I am working on a specific project and it uses Django and DRF, which I installed using pipenv install. I have a problem with pipenv since for example I tried to install cryptography and it went through the steps and said installation successful but when I tried importing the module it gave me a module not found error. I can see the module is mentioned in my pipfile so why can I not import it. My environment is set to the one I started when I said pipenv shell so why is it not picking up the module? I did not touch the PATH and pipenv install worked fine for Django and DRF and some other modules. Then I did a pip3 install cryptography and now it works. So why does it work with pip3 and not pipenv? Also why if you installed a module are you able to run pipenv install for the same module over and over again? shouldn't it just tell you the module is already installed and skip the process? Is there a better package manager I can use instead of pipenv?

Comment: You can try to activate your venv by `pipenv shell` and check what packages are installed inside it with `pip freeze`. The problem with package installation could occur with specific environment. As an alternative you can try to use a simple `venv` package or more sophisticated `poetry`.

Comment: is your virtual env active when you installed cryptography using pipenv ?